# WFFM. "Collection is read-only" when trying to add field in designer

Tags: wffm

Upgraded from WFFM 2.4 to 8.2u1. Forms that already exist is able to add new fields and edit in any way.

If i create a new form and try to press "Add field" in the form designer this error pops up:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: please, post the exception stacktrace as text, so that i could be googled in future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by a missing sub-item within the Web Forms for Marketers base form creation process.  To fix this until Sitecore corrects the issue:

1. Go into the Content Editor and find your Form
2. Right click on your form and insert a new Form Section (or select it and use your insert options)
3. Give it a name

That should get you working again.  Until a fix is ready, I have created a basic form with just a "Fields" section and instead of creating a new form, I just click the button to copy from an existing form.

Comment: I made a branch template in wait for this to work, so that the section comes with the creation of a form. Thanks for the workaround tip!

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore provided a support package for this issue. You can find it under https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/844911.

Just copy the Sitecore.Support.139810.config and the Sitecore.Support.139810.dll from the package to your servers and the issue should be fixed.